# how to use type hint in python to perform that a method returns exactly its parameter

Tags: python-3.5, type-hinting

here is my basic code.

```
from typing import Optional


class State:
    name = 'unnamed state'

    def __init__(self, name: str = None) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        if name is not None:
            self.name = name

    def on_enter(self) -> None:
        pass

    def on_leave(self) -> None:
        pass

    def to(self, dest: Optional['State']) -> Optional['State']:
        self.on_leave()
        if dest is not None:
            dest.on_leave()
        return dest


class AState(State):
    pass


class BState(State):
    def b_func(self):
        pass


a = AState()
b = BState()

a.to(b).b_func()
```

currently type hint shows the type of `a.to(b)` is `Optional[State]`, but what I wanted is to return the parameter is self, which is `BState`. Is this available in the type system in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to have a function always return exactly the same type as its parameter, you can use generics via the [TypeVars](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-functions) class:

```
from typing import Optional, TypeVar

# Note that "TState" is an arbitrary name.
TState = TypeVar('TState', bound='State')

class State:
    name = 'unnamed state'

    def __init__(self, name: str = None) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        if name is not None:
            self.name = name

    def on_enter(self) -> None:
        pass

    def on_leave(self) -> None:
        pass

    def to(self, dest: Optional[TState]) -> Optional[TState]:
        self.on_leave()
        if dest is not None:
            dest.on_leave()
        return dest


class AState(State):
    pass


class BState(State):
    def b_func(self):
        pass


a = AState()
b = BState()

a.to(b).b_func()
```

The expression `TState = TypeVar('TState', bound=State)` means "create a new generic parameter named `TState` which must always be a subclass of a `State` object." However, since the `State` class isn't defined yet, we need to use a forward reference and have the bound be a string instead of the class name: `TState = TypeVar('TState', bound='State')`.

You could also do `TState = TypeVar('TState')` which means "create a new generic parameter named `TState` which can be anything", but that probably isn't what you want so I don't recommend it.

You can learn more about upper bounds in TypeVars here: http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds